# is it possible to reopen the default System.in stream?

Tags: java, networking, io, stream

I have a very simple and weird question.
consider the following

```
void close(InputStream is){
   is.close();
}
```

and assume we pass the default `System.in`(keyboard) stream to it to close.

The question is, once we close the `System.in`, is it possible to reopen it again?! is there any class that represents the `System.in` directive?

and another question is, what if `System.in` gets closed?!

and the last question, why can't we close the `System.in` while another thread is reading from it? is it kinda locking? or what?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: Even if these things are possible, this is just... all wrong. Don't close a file if it is, or might be, standard input, and you might need to read from standard input in future!

Comment: @isnot2bad What do I suppose to try?! I'm asking for a class/member. I also checked that I cannot close the stream while another thread is reading from it(blocked)

Comment: @parsaporahmad you're right. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I bet somehow it is possible to reopen it, since considering the JavaDoc "it is already opened". Of course it has to be opened by default, but I am not aware of a method to reopen it. I can imagine using some natives, fiddling around with exec or probably really some simple stuff will help.

If the stream gets closed, nothing special happens. I just tried it. It works as with any other stream. You only lose your System.in, which is kind of ... sad itself.

There is most presumably some locking involved. Without synchronizing you could get dirty reads and such stuff.

But: You. Do. Not. Want. To. Close. Your. Standard. Input. Stream. Period.

Comment: So you are saying what I'm saying, so how to?! I know this may possible like you mentioned, but how? you mentioned a method, the name?

Comment: It is possible. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream) Will help you. You only have to figure out how to get the stream from your OS and pass it to that function. -- What shall I answer to the second question? What can happen if you close a stream? Nothing. It's closed. -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read() "This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown." So basically you can't close it because the access to the stream is blocked by the wait.